# java network multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, network-programming, threadpool

I am trying to build a server that can concurrently accept files from multiple clients.

But it is submitting files sequentially and I don't understand why....

Can anyone help? Thank you

I post my snippet of two threads. everytime I accept connection, I instantiate Submission class and execute them.

```
This is main thread that accepts connections
int poolSize = 1; 
    int maxPoolSize = 3;
    long keepAliveTime = 10;
    ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(5);
    threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(poolSize, maxPoolSize, keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS, queue);
```

Comment: what you mean by "And it seems like 'clientServer.accept()' is blocking." this should be a blocking call and should wait until a client connects to the server. Are you setting a timeout on clientServer object ?

Comment: it looks fine what is it that makes you believe its not running in parallel? As a side note if you run this under tomcat clients can submit files via http post and you get all this for free.

Comment: Are you submitting files concurrently? Are you using all your network bandwidth with just one connection?

Comment: Which part of your program takes a long time? Right now just about the only thing the Submission does is log everything, and this is done inside a lock, so it's not really surprising that it doesn't happen concurrently. That's the whole purpose of a lock...

Btw., why don't you use synchronized(lock) { ... }?

Comment: It looks like you edited your code snippets and remove much of the relevant code.  This will make it much harder for future readers of this question to understand the answers below.  May I suggest if you wanted to get new comments for where your code is after working on it, that you add it under the old snippets or create a new question. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lock in the run() method of Submission class is causing that portion of your code to run sequentially.  That lock is passed in via the constructor so it's shared between all your children, so they all call lock.lock() before running the stats.logSubmission.  Which means only one thread at a time is going to call logSubmission.

As a quick way to get this concurrent; try removing the lock and instead of writing to files right away, try storing the logs records in a [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html). You can then flush them to disk at some later point in execution or on some condition (size, time,..).  That queue is a lock-free, fast and thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you need to separate the thread where you `.accept()` new connections, and where you handle those requests.

Every time you call `.accept()` on the server socket, spawn a new thread to handle that request, and pass into that thread the socket connection from the `.accept()` method.